# Check that $f_a$ is a density function

Tags: probability-theory

For $a\in[-1,1]$, we note $f_a(x)=f_Z(x)(1+a\sin(2\pi\log(x))1_{\mathbb{R}_+}(x)$.

Prove that $f_a$ is a density function, where

$f_Z(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\log{x})^2}{2}}$,  is the log-normal distribution.

My partial solution:

I should prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_a(x)dx=1$,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_a(x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f_Z(x)(1+a\sin(2\pi\log(x))dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\log{x})^2}{2}} (1+a\sin(2\pi\log(x))dx$,

Comment: Just integrate it and show that its mass is $1$.

Comment: maybe the change of variable $u=\log(x)$ is useful.